# Swift Reflection Type Checking

Tags: swift, reflection, types, dynamictype

I'm currently experimenting with Swift reflection and subscripting. In my class, I have the following function to check whether a given key/variable exists:

```
func getMirror(key: String) -> MirrorType? {
    let mirror = reflect(self)
    for i in 0..<mirror.count {
        let (name,type) = mirror[i]
        if name == key { return type }
    }
    return nil 
}
```

Then, in the subscript declaration, I do the following:

```
subscript(key: String) -> AnyObject? {
   ...
   set(newValue) {
        if let mirror : MirrorType = getMirror(key) {
            var type : Any.Type = mirror.valueType
            // Check here whether newValue is castable as type
        }
   }
}
```

The question is now whether there's a possibility to check if newValue can be safely set for the respective variable via

```
self.setValue(newValue, forKey: key)
```

which returns an exception if the value is not settable. If a have a Swift.Int or Swift.Double variable

```
println(type)
```

or

```
toString(type)
```

gives me exactly these names of the types. But is there a way to probe casting of newValue to these types? I can't directly compare strings because

```
newValue.dynamicType
```

returns Swift.Optional or __NSCFNumber for instance if unwrapped. I've tried with NSClassFromString, but it doesn't seem to work with Swift native types. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Edit:

One thing in additional: I've also tried the following

```
if let convertedValue: AnyObject = mirror.value as? AnyObject {
    var type = convertedValue.dynamicType
}
```

and then I could for instance use

```
newValue!.isKindOfClass(type)
```

However, if I have an optional in the class which is not yet instantiated, this doesn't work, as mirror.value is nil. Also, newValue might still be convertable to the required type.

Comment: If you want to do that right and have support for any type, then you need quite some code. Here is some code how to get the right value from your mirror.value. https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection/blob/0879793e6d4ed5e554211eea7d654c7a0bfcdb82/EVReflection/pod/EVReflection.swift#L434-434

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've already seen the project, but even they try casting a lot of different values rather than dynamically casting to the type returned by the MirrorType object ... Maybe I'll figure something out, I'll post it here in case I got something!

Comment: If you find out how to do that, then i'm very interested in that. I'm almost certain there is no other way to do this. EVReflection is my library :-)

Comment: the reason why this is needed is that the mirror.value is of type Any. The .setValue needs to be of type AnyObject. Numbers like Uint16 and Uint32 are of type any. They need to converted to a NSNumber.

Comment: The question whether there is a way to catch potential errors of the .setValue function before calling it? If this function is called with wrong values, I get an exception, and I would like to know whether the function will fail.

Comment: do {
                try anyObject.validateValue(&value, forKey: key)
                anyObject.setValue(value, forKey: key)
            } catch _ {
            }

Comment: And for an optional you can get the type (after .count check) with Mirror(reflecting: theValue).children.first!.value.dynamicType

Comment: Thank you (if a little late). I wasn't aware of the validateValue method, wrapping that in try/catch did the job!